Как поменять backgroundTint у Button android studio
Мне нужно поменять backgroundTint у Button именно в коде в MainActivity.java
передать цвет нужно через @color
setBackgroundTintMode(R.color.mainBlue);

так не работает и с List и BlendMode тоже;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801031/how-to-add-button-tint-programmatically

setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name));

contextInstance - то, где хотите поменять backgroundTint;
